# Selenium can't find button after tweet

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twitter

I'm coding bot in python to automaticly send tweets from file to my Twitter wall. First tweet is posted correctly, but the further the worse, after first posting selenium having problems with finding Tweet button and clicking it, sometimes two tweets are posting at the same time etc. How to fix it?

```
def post_tweets(driver):
    tweets = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'\\tweets.txt', 'r')
    for tweet in tweets:
        time.sleep(3)
        try:
            textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.notranslate')))
            textbox.send_keys(tweet)
            try:
                send_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.r-urgr8i:nth-child(4)')))
            except:
                return
            send_button.click()
        except:
           return
```

Comment: Examine any exceptions that might be occurring instead of just `return`ing. There's valuable information that you're not seeing at all.

Comment: I tried
except Exception as e:
print(e)
But as you know it's not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I fixed it. Just replaced CSS_SELECTOR with XPATH.

```
def post_tweets(driver):
    tweets = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'\\tweets.txt', 'r')
    time.sleep(2)
    for tweet in tweets:
        time.sleep(1)
        textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.notranslate')))
        textbox.send_keys(tweet)
        send_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]')))
        send_button.click()
```